# Schema Migrations and Default Values

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm using South to manage my databases. It seems like every time I change something minor in the way my models are created, I end up having to do a bunch of gymnastics for the migrations. For instance, let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    text = models.TextField()
```

and another class that has `Entry` as a ForeignKey:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

This is trivial, but if I were to do something as simple as change the name pubDate to pub_date in `Entry`, in order to properly perform schema migration just for this name change, I would have to set:

```
default=None, null=True
```

for both pubDate in `Entry` AND the `entry` field in `Comment`, otherwise I would get the following exception when trying to run the migration:

```
The field 'Comment.entry' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
```

THEN I would have to go back and take out the default/null values. Is there a less tedious way to do this, or do I just have to REALLY think out my models before committing them to migrations? In the beginning stages, does it make more sense just to set up and tear down the database if you don't have any data you care about keeping? If so, what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need create a migration class, using:

```
python manage.py datamigration yourapp change_name_to_pub_date
```

and rewrite the forwards and backwards methods:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_column('yourapp_entry', 'pubDate', 'pub_date')
        db.rename_column('yourapp_comment', 'pubDate', 'pub_date')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_column('yourapp_entry', 'pub_date', 'pubDate')
        db.rename_column('yourapp_comment', 'pub_date', 'pubDate')
```

and now, run:

```
python manage.py migrate yourapp
```